# Deny access to website folders

Tags: html, .htaccess, permissions, directory

I have seen several websites: for example
http://www.website.com/images/pic001.jpg
And when I try to access http://www.website.com/images/ is prohibited.
That is exactly what I want to protect my folders from curious.
How I can I accomplish this?
Adding some instructions into the. htaccess?
Changing Folder permissions?
Thanks, I hope I explained well, and sorry for my horrible way of writing in English
P.D.: My website is hosted on 000webhost.
Grettings!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add `Options -Indexes` into the .htaccess file in the images folder, this results in a forbidden message if one tries to access /images/, but access to /images/pic001.jpg is still possible.

For more information see here: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

Comment: Excellent, just what I wanted!

Comment: I know this is old but it is the same question I am searching for. Does this mean if I have other folders like /js or /css that I want to restrict access, I have to create .htaccess file for each folder?

Comment: nvm, I figured out. In my case I am using cPanel, So go to Advanced > Indexes. Choose the directory and click No Indexing > Save

Answer (score 3):

You likely mean to allow access to the images but preventing browsing. You can disable browsing of a folder when there is no index if you add `Options -Indexes` into your .htaccess in your images folder.