# .htaccess does not work as it should be

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to deny access to folders on my website. Exactly the same question as here [Deny access to website folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128068/deny-access-to-website-folders).

I added Options -Indexes into the .htaccess file in the images folder. No effect. I add Deny from all into the .htaccess file in the root folder. No effect.

There is my website - http://www.mob1c.ru and this is the folder I want to deny access to - http://www.mob1c.ru/images

I have Windows 2012, Apache 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Just find the solution:
1. in httpd.conf should be line: AccessFileName .htaccess
2. in httpd.conf should be lines:
 
    AllowOverride **All**