# How to embed a PDF in my shiny application run on an AWS server without using www folder?

Tags: r, image, pdf, shiny

I know how to use `tags$iframe` with `src` pointing to my `pdf` or `jpeg` file located in my `www` folder like this question explains: [displaying a pdf from a local drive in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469978/displaying-a-pdf-from-a-local-drive-in-shiny)

My problem, however, is that I do not want to make the files publicly accessible through the `www` folder. To avoid this, I have tried using `imageOutput()` and `renderImage()` and gotten picture files to work reasonably-well.

My issue still remains with the `pdfs` which do not load using `imageOutput`. How can I embed a `pdf` in my shiny-app without making it publicly available in the `www` folder. Ideally, this solution would also work with `jpeg` and other picture files as well.

The `iframe` solution is perfect except for its publicly available `www` folder

Comment: Depending on which part of your file system is not public, you could add it with `addResourcePath()`: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/addResourcePath.html?

Comment: `When pages are loaded with a HTTP(S) protocol (the case of the Shiny app) for security reasons you can't framed locals files with their file: URLs.` I see this a lot. Would using `addResourcePath()` avoid these security reasons? Sorry I'm not very familiar with all of this

Comment: I used `addResourcePath()` and it worked. but there still seems to be a URL that anyone can access without going through my app's password UI.

Mainly by just typing in: `mywebsite.com/new_path/path_to_file.pdf`

Comment: i am not an expert in website security, but i would attempt creating a directory where undesired access is blocked (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128068/deny-access-to-website-folders) and then use this directory as a resource path,..